# Looping through Word documents

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a procedure which programmatically opens and reads the contents of a Word file. The time taken by the procedure is obviously proportional to the size of the document but on average 100 documents can be read in about 8 minutes. Occasionally, I get the following Word error:

> The file is in use by another application or user.
>   (C:...\Templates\Normal.dotm). This error is commonly encountered
>   when a read lock is set on the file that you are attempting to open.

Subsequently the procedure ends up calling an endless number of Word.exe processes and Task Manager quickly fills up.

Q) How can I improve my procedure to wait before launching a new Word process for the reading of the next file. Right now it seems dependent on the time taken to read the previous file. - Thanks

```
 private void readWordDoc(bool reportMode, string file)
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            object path = @file;
            object readOnly = true;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
            string totaltext = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
            {
                totaltext += "\n" + docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString();
            }
            docs.Close();
            word.Quit();

            if (!reportMode)
            {
                rtxtDocViewer.Text = totaltext;
            }

            if (reportMode)
            {
                writeReport(totaltext, file);
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error loading doc. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: have you considered OpenXML ? This will eliminate the need to open word and filling up your task manager.

Comment: No, but I'll look.... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting for the previous Word process to die before spawning the next one.

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19577783/563088

It might take the Word process some time to really close and if the loop starts the next Word process before the previous one closed they might be loading the same template at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [OpenXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) (if the doc-files are saved using the correct file formats) for the job. It will eliminate the problem with filling up task manager, and you can more easily use parallelism.

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code helped remedy the situation in the end:

```
 word.NormalTemplate.Saved = true;
```

.

```
 private void readWordDoc(bool reportMode, string file)
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            object miss = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

            object path = @file;
            object readOnly = true;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document docs = word.Documents.Open(ref path, ref miss, ref readOnly, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss, ref miss);
            string totaltext = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < docs.Paragraphs.Count; i++)
            {
                totaltext += "\n" + docs.Paragraphs[i + 1].Range.Text.ToString();
            }
            docs.Close();
            word.NormalTemplate.Saved = true;
            word.Quit();

            if (!reportMode)
            {
                rtxtDocViewer.Text = totaltext;
            }

            if (reportMode)
            {
                writeReport(totaltext, file);
            }                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("Error loading doc. " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
```